# android list audio on sd card and play it

Tags: android, media-player, sd-card

i am getting the audio files information in sdcard using

```
cr = getContentResolver();
crsrSdcard_ringtone = cr.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null,
     null, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
```

now i want to play particular file from the list can i do it with passing it like

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlay = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlay.setDataSource(this,Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "/"+id));

mediaPlay.prepare();
mediaPlay.start();
```

please suggest a solution to get the file being played.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the above code? Please post logCat. Also, you might want to try using try and catch statements to figure out if your player fails in any of the above stages of prepare, start or setDataSource. The errors can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i recently come to know about _data field no 1 in the cursor returned crsrSdcard_ringtone will contain real path(/sdcard/Doorbell.mp3) to the file which will be useful to play that file which we can use with setDataSource() function of MediaPlayer